# Failed to transform flutter.jar to match attributes

Tags: java, android, flutter, gradle

I am having an issue when I run my flutter app.

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':flutter_appcenter_bundle:compileDebugKotlin'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':flutter_appcenter_bundle:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Failed to transform flutter.jar to match attributes {artifactType=android-classes, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for JetifyTransform: C:\Flutter\bin\cache\artifacts\engine\android-x64\flutter.jar.
         > Failed to transform 'C:\Flutter\bin\cache\artifacts\engine\android-x64\flutter.jar' using Jetifier. Reason: Cannot open a library at 'FileMapping(from=C:\Flutter\bin\cache\artifacts\engine\android-x64\flutter.jar, to=C:\Users\Anton\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\bb1623c867f6cdcbdfa4a85290968351\jetified-flutter.jar)'. (Run with --stacktrace for more details.)
```

Flutter Doctor:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.6, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19042.804], locale en-ZA)
    • Flutter version 1.22.6 at C:\Flutter
    • Framework revision 9b2d32b605 (3 weeks ago), 2021-01-22 14:36:39 -0800
    • Engine revision 2f0af37152
    • Dart version 2.10.5


[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\Anton\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.2
    • ANDROID_SDK_ROOT = C:\Users\Anton\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[!] Android Studio (version 4.1.0)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    ✗ Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    ✗ Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.53.2)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\Anton\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.19.0

[✓] Connected device (1 available)
    • sdk gphone x86 arm (mobile) • emulator-5554 • android-x86 • Android 11 (API 30) (emulator)

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

What I have tried to solve the issue.

1. I have reinstalled Flutter.
2. Deleted gradle cache in Users/MyUserName/.gradle/cahce
3. Deleted the whole .gradle folder in Users/MyUserName/.gradle
4. Reinstalled Gradle.
5. Cloned the project again from repo without /build folder.
6. Ran flutter clean.
7. Ran gradle clean.
8. Uninstalled gradle and downgraded to 5.6.4
9. Tried various solutions from stackoverflow from users with a similar problem.
10. Reinstalled Android Studio

I have flutter in my environment variable as well as gradle and 100% its working.

Running my assemble with a stacktrace I get:

```
❯ gradle assembleQADebug --stacktrace

> Configure project :flutter_appcenter_bundle
FLUTTER_ROOT: C:\Flutter

> Task :flutter_appcenter_bundle:compileDebugKotlin FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':flutter_appcenter_bundle:compileDebugKotlin'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':flutter_appcenter_bundle:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Failed to transform file 'flutter.jar' to match attributes {artifactType=android-classes, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}
      > Execution failed for JetifyTransform: C:\Flutter\bin\cache\artifacts\engine\android-x64\flutter.jar.
         > Failed to transform 'C:\Flutter\bin\cache\artifacts\engine\android-x64\flutter.jar' using Jetifier. Reason: Cannot open a library at 'FileMapping(from=C:\Flutter\bin\cache\artifacts\engine\android-x64\flutter.jar, to=C:\Users\Anton\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\497c7c322859abf830189fdb198b5ca1\jetified-flutter.jar)'. (Run with --stacktrace for more details.)

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':flutter_appcenter_bundle:compileDebugKotlin'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:38)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:77)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:55)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:416)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:406)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:102)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:43)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:355)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:343)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:336)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:322)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:134)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:129)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:202)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeNextNode(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:193)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:129)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':flutter_appcenter_bundle:debugCompileClasspath'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.rethrowFailure(DefaultConfiguration.java:1258)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.access$2200(DefaultConfiguration.java:139)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$ConfigurationArtifactCollection.ensureResolved(DefaultConfiguration.java:1712)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$ConfigurationArtifactCollection.getArtifacts(DefaultConfiguration.java:1684)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.ArtifactCollectionWithExtraArtifact.getArtifacts(ArtifactCollectionWithExtraArtifact.java:119)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.ArtifactCollectionWithExtraArtifact.iterator(ArtifactCollectionWithExtraArtifact.java:133)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.Android25ProjectHandler$wireKotlinTasks$2.invoke(Android25ProjectHandler.kt:245)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.Android25ProjectHandler$wireKotlinTasks$2.invoke(Android25ProjectHandler.kt:29)
        at kotlin.SynchronizedLazyImpl.getValue(LazyJVM.kt:74)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile.setupCompilerArgs(Tasks.kt:403)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile.setupCompilerArgs(Tasks.kt:359)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.CompilerArgumentAware$DefaultImpls.setupCompilerArgs$default(CompilerArgumentAware.kt:40)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.CompilerArgumentAwareKt.prepareCompilerArguments(CompilerArgumentAware.kt:44)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.CompilerArgumentAwareKt.prepareCompilerArguments$default(CompilerArgumentAware.kt:43)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.CompilerArgumentAware$DefaultImpls.getFilteredArgumentsMap(CompilerArgumentAware.kt:37)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.CompilerArgumentAwareWithInput$DefaultImpls.getFilteredArgumentsMap(CompilerArgumentAware.kt:61)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.AbstractKotlinCompileTool.getFilteredArgumentsMap(Tasks.kt:52)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile_Decorated.getFilteredArgumentsMap(Unknown Source)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.properties.bean.AbstractNestedRuntimeBeanNode$BeanPropertyValue$1$1.create(AbstractNestedRuntimeBeanNode.java:80)
        at org.gradle.util.SingleMessageLogger.whileDisabled(SingleMessageLogger.java:467)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.properties.bean.AbstractNestedRuntimeBeanNode$BeanPropertyValue$1.get(AbstractNestedRuntimeBeanNode.java:76)
        at com.google.common.base.Suppliers$NonSerializableMemoizingSupplier.get(Suppliers.java:167)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.properties.bean.AbstractNestedRuntimeBeanNode$BeanPropertyValue.call(AbstractNestedRuntimeBeanNode.java:148)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.properties.AbstractValidatingProperty.validate(AbstractValidatingProperty.java:37)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.properties.DefaultTaskProperties.validate(DefaultTaskProperties.java:193)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:108)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveBeforeExecutionOutputsTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveBeforeExecutionOutputsTaskExecuter.java:67)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveAfterPreviousExecutionStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveAfterPreviousExecutionStateTaskExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:94)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:95)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:56)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
        ... 24 more
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.TransformException: Failed to transform file 'flutter.jar' to match attributes {artifactType=android-classes, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.TransformingArtifactVisitor.lambda$visitFile$3(TransformingArtifactVisitor.java:90)
        at org.gradle.internal.Try$Failure.ifSuccessfulOrElse(Try.java:191)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.TransformingArtifactVisitor.visitFile(TransformingArtifactVisitor.java:84)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.artifact.LocalFileDependencyBackedArtifactSet$SingletonFileResolvedVariant.visit(LocalFileDependencyBackedArtifactSet.java:171)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.TransformCompletion.visit(TransformCompletion.java:42)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.artifact.CompositeResolvedArtifactSet$CompositeResult.visit(CompositeResolvedArtifactSet.java:83)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.artifact.ParallelResolveArtifactSet$VisitingSet.visit(ParallelResolveArtifactSet.java:65)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration.visitArtifacts(DefaultLenientConfiguration.java:261)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration.access$500(DefaultLenientConfiguration.java:69)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$2.run(DefaultLenientConfiguration.java:236)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:402)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:394)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:92)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration.visitArtifactsWithBuildOperation(DefaultLenientConfiguration.java:233)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration.access$200(DefaultLenientConfiguration.java:69)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$1.visitArtifacts(DefaultLenientConfiguration.java:133)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$ConfigurationArtifactCollection.ensureResolved(DefaultConfiguration.java:1706)
        ... 56 more
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.TransformException: Execution failed for JetifyTransform: C:\Flutter\bin\cache\artifacts\engine\android-x64\flutter.jar.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.DefaultTransformerInvoker$2.lambda$call$1(DefaultTransformerInvoker.java:221)
        at org.gradle.internal.Try$Failure.mapFailure(Try.java:182)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.DefaultTransformerInvoker$2.lambda$call$2(DefaultTransformerInvoker.java:221)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.DefaultTransformerInvoker.fireTransformListeners(DefaultTransformerInvoker.java:276)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.DefaultTransformerInvoker.access$300(DefaultTransformerInvoker.java:76)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.DefaultTransformerInvoker$2.call(DefaultTransformerInvoker.java:179)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.DefaultTransformerInvoker$2.call(DefaultTransformerInvoker.java:176)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:416)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:406)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:102)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.DefaultTransformerInvoker.lambda$doTransform$0(DefaultTransformerInvoker.java:176)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.ImmutableTransformationWorkspaceProvider.lambda$withWorkspace$0(ImmutableTransformationWorkspaceProvider.java:81)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.LockOnDemandCrossProcessCacheAccess.withFileLock(LockOnDemandCrossProcessCacheAccess.java:90)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.withFileLock(DefaultCacheAccess.java:194)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.withFileLock(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:172)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheFactory$ReferenceTrackingCache.withFileLock(DefaultCacheFactory.java:196)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.ImmutableTransformationWorkspaceProvider.withWorkspace(ImmutableTransformationWorkspaceProvider.java:76)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.AbstractCachingTransformationWorkspaceProvider.lambda$withWorkspace$0(AbstractCachingTransformationWorkspaceProvider.java:56)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalManualCache$1.load(LocalCache.java:4718)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3445)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2194)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2153)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2043)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3851)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalManualCache.get(LocalCache.java:4713)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.AbstractCachingTransformationWorkspaceProvider.withWorkspace(AbstractCachingTransformationWorkspaceProvider.java:55)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.DefaultTransformerInvoker.doTransform(DefaultTransformerInvoker.java:176)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.DefaultTransformerInvoker.access$000(DefaultTransformerInvoker.java:76)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.DefaultTransformerInvoker$1.invoke(DefaultTransformerInvoker.java:142)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.CacheableInvocation$1.invoke(CacheableInvocation.java:58)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.CacheableInvocation.lambda$flatMap$3(CacheableInvocation.java:77)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.CacheableInvocation$3.invoke(CacheableInvocation.java:111)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.TransformationOperation.run(TransformationOperation.java:39)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:402)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:394)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.access$1500(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:49)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$ParentPreservingQueueWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:444)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationQueue$WorkerRunnable.runOperation(DefaultBuildOperationQueue.java:231)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationQueue$WorkerRunnable.access$600(DefaultBuildOperationQueue.java:173)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationQueue$WorkerRunnable$1.create(DefaultBuildOperationQueue.java:210)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationQueue$WorkerRunnable$1.create(DefaultBuildOperationQueue.java:204)
        at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:189)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationQueue$WorkerRunnable.runBatch(DefaultBuildOperationQueue.java:204)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationQueue$WorkerRunnable.run(DefaultBuildOperationQueue.java:178)
        ... 3 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to transform 'C:\Flutter\bin\cache\artifacts\engine\android-x64\flutter.jar' using Jetifier. Reason: Cannot open a library at 'FileMapping(from=C:\Flutter\bin\cache\artifacts\engine\android-x64\flutter.jar, to=C:\Users\Anton\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\497c7c322859abf830189fdb198b5ca1\jetified-flutter.jar)'. (Run with --stacktrace for more details.)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.JetifyTransform.transform(JetifyTransform.kt:118)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.LegacyTransformer.transform(LegacyTransformer.java:77)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.DefaultTransformerInvoker$TransformerExecution.execute(DefaultTransformerInvoker.java:339)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.lambda$execute$1(ExecuteStep.java:33)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:33)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:26)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CleanupOutputsStep.execute(CleanupOutputsStep.java:58)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CleanupOutputsStep.execute(CleanupOutputsStep.java:35)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:48)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:33)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CancelExecutionStep.execute(CancelExecutionStep.java:39)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.executeWithoutTimeout(TimeoutStep.java:73)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.execute(TimeoutStep.java:54)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CatchExceptionStep.execute(CatchExceptionStep.java:35)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CreateOutputsStep.execute(CreateOutputsStep.java:51)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SnapshotOutputsStep.execute(SnapshotOutputsStep.java:45)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SnapshotOutputsStep.execute(SnapshotOutputsStep.java:31)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CacheStep.executeWithoutCache(CacheStep.java:208)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CacheStep.execute(CacheStep.java:70)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CacheStep.execute(CacheStep.java:45)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.execute(BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.java:49)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreSnapshotsStep.execute(StoreSnapshotsStep.java:43)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreSnapshotsStep.execute(StoreSnapshotsStep.java:32)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:38)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:24)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.executeBecause(SkipUpToDateStep.java:96)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.lambda$execute$0(SkipUpToDateStep.java:89)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:54)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:38)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:76)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:37)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:36)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:26)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:90)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:48)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:69)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:47)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.DefaultWorkExecutor.execute(DefaultWorkExecutor.java:33)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.DefaultTransformerInvoker$2.lambda$call$2(DefaultTransformerInvoker.java:202)
        ... 51 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Cannot open a library at 'FileMapping(from=C:\Flutter\bin\cache\artifacts\engine\android-x64\flutter.jar, to=C:\Users\Anton\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\497c7c322859abf830189fdb198b5ca1\jetified-flutter.jar)'
        at com.android.tools.build.jetifier.processor.Processor.loadLibraries(Processor.kt:388)
        at com.android.tools.build.jetifier.processor.Processor.transform(Processor.kt:241)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.JetifyTransform.transform(JetifyTransform.kt:113)
        ... 89 more


* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 6.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/5.6.4/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 1m 9s
79 actionable tasks: 79 executed
```

Please let me know if I can add any other information that might help me solve this issue.

Comment: I still havent found a solution to this

Answer (score 5):

Try running flutter precache before running the build again. This worked for me.

Comment: Hi, Do you mean flutter image precache?